# Showing value's data with RegGetValue

Tags: c, winapi

I am trying to understand how to use the PVOID data type in the WinApi, so I tried to show a value called MyValue (it is a DWORD value) using RegGetValue function, but It did not work for me.

Here is my code:

```
int wmain()
{
    LONG openKey;
    HKEY hKey = HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
    LPCWSTR subKey = L"WinSide\\Config";
    DWORD options = 0;
    REGSAM samDesired = KEY_READ | KEY_WRITE;

    //Allocating memory for a HKEy value.
    PHKEY pkOpenResult = (PHKEY)malloc(sizeof(HKEY));

    //GetValue
    LONG getValue;
    LPCWSTR pValue = L"MyValue";
    DWORD flags = RRF_RT_ANY;

    //Allocationg memory for a DWORD value.
    LPDWORD dataType = (LPDWORD)malloc(sizeof(DWORD));

    WCHAR value[255];

    PVOID pvData = (PVOID)value; //No idea if this is the rigth way.
    DWORD size = 8192;
    LPDWORD pcbData = &size;

    openKey = RegOpenKeyEx(hKey, subKey, options,
                            samDesired, pkOpenResult);

    if (openKey != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        wprintf(L"The %s subkey could not be opened. Error code: %li\n", subKey, openKey);
        free(pkOpenResult);
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(L"Subkey opened!\n");
        getValue = RegGetValue(*pkOpenResult, NULL, pValue, flags, dataType, pvData, pcbData);

        if (getValue != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            wprintf(L"Error getting value. Code: %li\n", getValue);
            free(pkOpenResult);
        }
        else
        {
            wprintf(L"Value data: %s\n", pvData);
            free(pkOpenResult);
        }
    }


    return 0;   

}
```

This is what the command prompt shows:

> Subkey opened! Value data: ?

No idea how I should declare and use the pvData value to show the rigth content.

Can you help me?

There were another similar posts, but I did not understand their code, so decided to show my own.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Check the `dataType` in order to know what kind of data you are getting..

Comment: dataType is 4, witch, I believe, stands for DWORD because I have a DWORD value in the registry subkey.

Comment: So why are you printing it as a string?

Comment: Cool. Can you tell me what mistakes I have, so I can correct them? I'm just trying to learn.

Comment: @EugeneSh. If I print it with the %li (I think that's the right one) It shows me a value like 7338968. I know I have mistakes, that's why I am asking for help.

Comment: It's a pointer. You have to dereference it before printing

Comment: I tried that, but VS says "Incomplete type is not allowed".

Comment: Because it is `void`. Cast it! I think you should start with simpler programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must select wprintf format (%x, %s, ..) based on dataType

> Can you tell me what mistakes I have, so I can correct them? I'm just
>   trying to learn

try for begin code like this:

```
int wmain()
{
    HKEY hKey = HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
    LPCWSTR subKey = L"WinSide\\Config";
    DWORD options = 0;
    REGSAM samDesired = KEY_READ;// | KEY_WRITE - need ?;

    HKEY OpenResult;

    LPCWSTR pValue = L"MyValue";
    DWORD flags = RRF_RT_ANY;

    //Allocationg memory for a DWORD value.
    DWORD dataType;

    WCHAR value[255];
    PVOID pvData = value;

    DWORD size = sizeof(value);// not 8192;

    LONG err = RegOpenKeyEx(hKey, subKey, options, samDesired, &OpenResult);

    if (err != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        wprintf(L"The %s subkey could not be opened. Error code: %x\n", subKey, err);
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(L"Subkey opened!\n");
        err = RegGetValue(OpenResult, NULL, pValue, flags, &dataType, pvData, &size);

        if (err != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            wprintf(L"Error getting value. Code: %x\n", err);
        }
        else
        {
            switch (dataType)
            {
            case REG_DWORD:
                wprintf(L"Value data: %x\n", *(DWORD*)pvData);
                break;
            case REG_SZ:
                //if ( !*((PWSTR)((PBYTE)pvData + size)-1) )
                wprintf(L"Value data: %s\n", (PWSTR)pvData);
                break;
                //...
            }
        }
        RegCloseKey(OpenResult);// don't forget !
    }

    return err;   
}
```

size != 8192;

RegCloseKey - where ?

```
   //Allocationg memory for a DWORD value.
    LPDWORD dataType = (LPDWORD)malloc(sizeof(DWORD));
```

horror

Comment: Um, the whole point of using `RegGetValue()` vs `RegQueryValueEx()` is that `RegGetValue()` null-terminates string data for you if it is not already null-terminated. You *do not* need to do it manually, like your example is doing (incorrectly, I might add).  And string data can be longer than 255 characters, `RegGetValue()` will fail if you try to read a value that is longer than your allocated buffer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau- yes, you right - when using RegGetValue not need check for 0 at the end. about data can be longer then 255(or any fixed size) - of course yes. but i simply minimal modify initial code, not try write perfect

Comment: @Checho i little edit code for remove extra check for null-terminated string in case REG_SZ

Comment: @RbMm: Thank you very much. I apologize for any bother. Have a last one question: why can't I use malloc to create the dataType variable pointer?

Comment: @Checho you of course can use malloc for allocate pkOpenResult, dataType. but why ?!? this is absolute senseless. also if you looking on your initial code - you not free dataType, call free for pkOpenResult from 3 place, when enough from one. you not check result of malloc. but main again : for what call  LPDWORD dataType = (LPDWORD)malloc(sizeof(DWORD)); use *dataType and finally free(dataType) when can simply use DWORD dataType; ?

Comment: That was I wanted to know. I was using malloc just to see if it worked. Thanks again.